# Подскажите с реализацией функции

Tags: php

Добрый день, подскажите, как реализована функция вопроса на ответ на сайте sprosimamu.ru?
Я так понимаю введенный вопрос случайным образом записывается в одну из двух таблиц в БД, таблица 1 - ответ "Да", таблица 2 - ответ "Нет" и выводится соответствующее изображение из БД?

Comment: Скорее всего таблица одна. Стркутура примерно такая
id(int) question(varchar или text в зависимости от количества знаков в впоросе) rait(enum или int)
При добавлении нового вопроса в поле rait записывается 1 или 2 .
1 - разрешено, 2 -запрещено.

Comment: @joe, купи себе Lego!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По ссылке ответа могу судить, что таблица для вопросов - одна ***['http://sprosimamu.ru/question/'] + [id]***

Вкратце:

- В общей таблице, помимо столбцов с id и вопросом, есть столбец для значений (1 или 0). Сам процесс рандома, можно сгенерировать ф-цей **mt_rand(0,1)**.
- Когда человек переходит по предоставленной ими странице (ответа «Мамы»). Принимается **GET** (он служит ***id***). По этому ***id***, из БД выбирается ваш вопрос и результат (1 или 0) (0=«НЕТ» и 1 = «ДА»).
- ну и собственно, уже исходя из результата (0 или 1), через **if-else** выводится сам ответ и картинка.

#### Предположительный алгоритм или альтернативный вариант для **php**:

- используется функция **mt_rand(0,1)**;
- предположим, есть БД ***questions***, с предположительной конструкцией MySQL:

  ```
      id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
      q TEXT COMMENT 'столбец для вопросов пользователей',
      result INT(1) UNSIGNED COMMENT 'столбец для ответов (0 или 1)'
  ```

  - проверяется, не задавался ли такой вопрос ранее.

    - Ищем в столбце q совпадения с заданным вопросом.
    - Если находим - возвращаем его на страницу:                             
          'http://sprosimamu.ru/question/index.php'
    - И тут у них проблемка! Теперь, ответ на один и тот же вопрос, всегда будет 
        одинаковым.
- если такого вопроса еще не задавали (мы не нашли его в БД), то добавляем его в БД:

  ```
   INSERT INTO questions(q,result) VALUES (q="задаваемый вопрос", result=$rand);
  ```
- когда кто-то переходит на предоставленную страницу ответа: ***'http://sprosimamu.ru/question/' + id***

  ```
   - принимаем GET-запрос (id);
   - достаем данные из БД:
       SELECT q,result FROM questions WHERE id=$GET;

   - выводим ответ, используем конструкцию if-else:    
       if($result == 1){
         // выводим картинку одобрения
         echo "Можно!";
       } else {
         // выводим картинку неодобрения
         echo "Нельзя!";
       }
  ```

  Как-то так